# sp_getapplock and ADO.Net Command Timeout

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Just curious, if I have a piece of T-SQL that is executed from ADO.Net (C#) which contains an sp_getapplock statement, and then the command was to timeout, will the Database server automatically release the lock  (Similar to if we had XACT_ABORT On for transactions)?

Comment: Check the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Can't see anything in there regarding ADO.Net command timeouts.  However, might be able to wrap it up in a Transaction, and have XACT_ABORT ON.  In theory, that should release the lock if the ADO.Net command times out.

Comment: "Locks associated with the session are released when the session is logged out." - when your timeout the session ends.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks, so when we close the connection, it is going to end the SPID and release the lock anyway.  Missed that ;)